# Add health check for Nginx in docker file

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, blazor-webassembly, kubernetes-health-check, health-check

I have a `WebAssmebly Blazor` App that runs locally, I deploy it to Azure K8s cluster using Helm,

The app pod keeps restarting when I checked the logs its complaining about health check that are missing

```
[21/Apr/2021:11:23:55 +0000] "GET /health/liveness HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "kube-probe/1.17" "-"
2021/04/21 11:23:55 [error] 31#31: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/health/liveness" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.244.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /health/liveness HTTP/1.1", host: "10.244.0.230:80"
```

Since `WebAssmebly Blazor` runs on the client side, a health isnt needed.

So, Im trying to write some static health check at Nginx level.

This is the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /source/app.CustomerApplication/
RUN dotnet publish -c release

FROM nginx AS runtime

COPY --from=publish /source/app.CustomerApplication/bin/release/netstandard2.1/publish/wwwroot/. /usr/share/nginx/html/.
COPY ./app.CustomerApplication/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

and Nginx config file:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location //health/liveness {
        return 200 'alive';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
cust-app       /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
cust-app       | 2021/04/20 23:56:16 [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
cust-app       | nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

Answer (score 1):

First `WebAssmebly Blazor` runs at the client side therefore to hackaround K8s health check I created static reply on specific routes in Nginx by modifying Nginx config file.
For a valid health check I recomamand to use `Server Blazor` type since its run on the server side, there is possibility to add an actual healthy check in `startup` class.

Regarding the issuer with `Nginx config` file the template I was was wrong, updated to this

```
server {
  #listen                80;
  #root                 /usr/share/nginx;

  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html; #sepecify Blazor app route
  }

  location /health/liveness {
    #access_log off;
    error_log   off;
    return 200 'ok';
  }

  location /health/readiness {
    #access_log off;
    error_log   off;
    return 200 'ok';
  }
}
```

Also an update is needed in `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /source/app.CustomerApplication/
RUN dotnet publish -c release

FROM nginx AS runtime

COPY --from=publish /source/app.CustomerApplication/bin/release/netstandard2.1/publish/wwwroot/. /usr/share/nginx/html/.
ADD ./app.CustomerApplication/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

K8s health check logs after updating Nginx:

```
10.244.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021:07:15:43 +0000] "GET /health/liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "kube-probe/1.17" "-"
10.244.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021:07:15:58 +0000] "GET /health/liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "kube-probe/1.17" "-"
```